# ExecuteNonQuery() - at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

Tags: c#, ssis

When executing C# code using Script Component of SSIS, I get this error:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Here, I am reading an excel file and dynamically create a sql server table on the file name and load the data.
This error is encountered while I am creating the Table (particularly while executing the statement "myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); )

Refer Code:-

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
 myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["LANDConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(tableDDL, myADONETConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please debug, and show us the sqlcommand that you are sending..

Comment: There is no error in your "error message".   You have not posted enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
public void Main()

{
String FolderPath=Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();    
 
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);                          

 FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

 string fileFullPath = "";

 foreach (FileInfo file in files)                                      

{

 string filename = "";

 fileFullPath = FolderPath+"\\"+file.Name;                    

 filename = file.Name.Replace(".xlsx","");                    

 string ConStr;

 string HDR;

 HDR="YES";

 ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +  
           fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + 
           HDR + ";IMEX=1\"";  

 OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

 cnn.Open();

 DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,  
                     null);  

 string sheetname;

 sheetname="";

 foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)

    {
       if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
         {
             sheetname=drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
             OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" +  
                                  sheetname + "]", cnn);
             OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             adp.Fill(dt);
             string tableDDL = "";
             tableDDL += "IF Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE 
                          object_id = ";
              tableDDL +="OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + filename +"]') AND  
                          type  in (N'U'))";
               tableDDL +=  "Create table [" + filename + "]";
               tableDDL += "(";
                 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                 {
                  if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                     tableDDL += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] "  
                              +   "NVarchar(max)" + ",";
                     else
                      tableDDL += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] "  
                                      + "NVarchar(max)";
                   }
                  tableDDL += ")";

                 SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                 myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)  
                 (Dts.Connections["Connection 
                  Manager"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as 
                           SqlConnection);
                 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(tableDDL,  
                  myADONETConnection);
                 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 
                 //Load the data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
                 SqlBulkCopy blk = new SqlBulkCopy(myADONETConnection);
                 blk.DestinationTableName = "[" + filename +"]";
                 blk.WriteToServer(dt);
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have used the above mentioned code to read data from an excel file and create tables dynamically from those excel files. But, getting mentioned error message especially at the myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  line. Please anybody suggest any option to correct me..